# Which must be true about the function f?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $A$ and $B$ be the two sets, such that $|A|=|B|$. There is a one to one function from $f:A\to B$.

Which of the following must be true about function $f$ ?

- $f$ is an onto function.
- $f$ has an inverse.

---

According to me, both are false if $A$ and $B$ are countable infinite set of Natural numbers.

So suppose, If there exists a function $f(i) = i^2$.

Well, in this case onto not possible which implies bijection not possible, hence no inverse possible .

---

But, I need some confirmation for my try .

Comment: Your counterexample is correct. However, you may also want to check the context of your original question (if this is from homework or a book) if there is some implicit assumption that $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, in which case $f$ will be onto and will have an inverse.

Comment: @angryavian Actually, I have typed the same. There is nothing extra or by default assumed .

Comment: You said the function is "one to".  What did you mean by that.

Comment: @fleablood: I imagine OP meant to write "one to one" or "injective."

Comment: @fleablood Consider that as typo. I've edited .

Answer (score 1):

If f is one-to-one then there is an inverse from the image of f, Im(f) to A:  $$ f^{-1}:Im (f)\subset B\rightarrow A $$ given by setting  $f^{-1}(x)=y $ where y is the unique  $y\in A $ such that $f (y)=x $.  But if $Imf\subsetneq B $, then $f^{-1} $ is not defined on all of B.  Since the image of your squaring function  $i\rightarrow i^2$ is the perfect squares,  the inverse is not defined on all of  $\mathbb N $...

Comment: Note though, that $f^{-1}$ can be extended to be a function on the domain of $\mathbb{N}$, such that it is a *left* inverse. So $f^{-1} (f(x)) = x$